# How to mock dispatch with jest.fn()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

For example, I want to know what has been dispatched and the argument. The action creator is asynchronous, but I don't care about its implementation, I just want to know if the component dispatches the correct action creator with the correct argument. I've tried this approach:

```
store.dispatch = jest.fn()
```

But I can't get any useful information:

[image: this is what I can get from store.dispatch.mock]

I've tried to solve the problem by this way:

```
expect(store.dispatch.mock.calls[0].toString()).toBe(requestArticles().toString())
```

But I don't know the argument and I'm sure, that there are a better way to do this. Also of note, I'm using react-testing-library, so I can't use `wrapper.instance().props` from Enzyme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock the action file and check if the action has been called.

e.g. Lets say `foo.action.js` is the file which has the action being dispatched.

in the start of your test file before importing the component, you can mock the file as:

```
const yourActionMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock('<Path to the action file>/foo.action.js', () => ({
  yourAction: yourActionMock
}));
```

now you can test the action called as:
`expect(yourActionMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<args>)`

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me, the mocked action is not being called for some reason.

Comment: You have to make sure that file is mocked before you import the component to be tested. If you are already doing it, Can you please share how you are dispatching your action.

Comment: I have already found a solution. I mocked the action without using a variable and then just checked was it called or not with redux-mock-store `store.getActions()`. 

This is a connected component and `requestArticles` is being passed from `mapDispatchToProps`. I'm not directly dispatching anything, I'm just simulating clicks.  Anyway, thanks a lot! Using `jest.mock` solved the problem.

Comment: getting this error: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.

Comment: Make sure the you write the variable name of your mock as `yourActionMock`.  using `mockYourAction` generates the error mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example that worked for me (2022):

**(Navbar.test.js)**

```
import store from "../../store/redux-store";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import { render, screen, cleanup, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import Navbar from "../navbar/Navbar";

describe("Navbar", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    // ! WE MAKE SURE THE MOCKS ARE CLEARED BEFORE EACH TEST CASE
    useSelectorMock.mockClear();
    useDispatchMock.mockClear();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  // ! SETUP THE SPY ON USESELECTOR / USE DISPATCH
  // ! WE DO THIS TO BE ABLE TO CHECK IF THE DISPATCH MOCK GOT CALLED AND HOW MANY TIMES
  const reactRedux = { useDispatch, useSelector }
  const useDispatchMock = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, "useDispatch");
  const useSelectorMock = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, "useSelector");

[...]

  test("cliking the sign-out button should sign out user", async () => {
    const mockStore = configureStore();
    const initialState = {
      auth: {
        isAuthModalOpen: false,
        user: { id: 1, email: "test@test.com" },
        notification: null,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        token: "ABC123",
      },
    };
    let updatedStore = mockStore(initialState);

    const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
    useDispatchMock.mockReturnValue(mockDispatch);
    updatedStore.dispatch = mockDispatch;
    // ? HERE THE INITIAL CONTENT OF THE MOCK
    // console.log(updatedStore.dispatch.mock);


    render(<Provider store={updatedStore}><Navbar /></Provider>);
    const signOutBtn = screen.getByTestId("button-sign-out");
    expect(signOutBtn).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(updatedStore.dispatch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    userEvent.click(signOutBtn);
    // ? HERE THE CONTENT OF THE MOCK CHANGED
    // console.log(updatedStore.dispatch.mock);

    expect(updatedStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(updatedStore.dispatch.mock.lastCall[0].type).toMatch("destroySession");
    screen.debug()

    console.log(updatedStore.getActions());
  });
```

Notice the difference in the way of importing "useDispatch" from react-redux.
Also, notice the way "mockDispatch" is attached to "updatedStore.dispatch".

Those 2 changes made it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using react-redux hooks you can do it like so:

```js
import * as reactRedux from 'react-redux';

const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
const mockUseDispatch = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, 'useDispatch');
```

and then make assertions on `mockDispatch` as usual.